# $\deg(\gcd(g(x),h(x))) >0$ if and only if there exist $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ such that $a(x)g(x) + b(x)h(x)=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, finite-fields

> Let $g(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $d$ and $h(x)$ be a polynomial of degree  $l$ over field $F$. If $\deg(\gcd(g,h)) > 0$ then there exist two polynomials $a(x)$, $b(x)$ of degrees $< l,d$ respectively such that $a(x)g(x) + b(x)h(x) = 0 $ and conversely.

By using extended Euclidean we can say that if  $\deg(\gcd(g,h)) > 0$ then there exist two polynomials $a(x)$, $b(x)$ of degrees $< l,d$ respectively such that $a(x)g(x) + b(x)h(x) = \gcd(g,h)$. I am not getting how it is $0$. And the second thing is how to prove the second direction.

**Reference** : http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~sk1233/courses/ANT-F14/lec10.pdf (4th Page)

Comment: Set $d=\gcd(g,h)$ with $\deg d\ge 1$, and write $g=dg_1$, $h=dh_1$. Then take $a=h_1$ and $b=-g_1$. For the second suppose $\gcd(g,h)=1$ and from $ag+bh=0$ conclude $g\mid b$, so $\deg b\ge\deg g=d$. That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a dimension counting exercise. Write $F[x]_d$ for the space of polynomials of degree at most $d$. Then $(a,b)\mapsto ag+bh$ is a linear map $F[x]_{l-1}\times F[x]_{d-1}\to F[x]_{l+d-1}$. Note carefully that the two spaces have the same dimension, so the map is onto if and only if it is injective.

I'll let you try to finish it yourself.

Comment: @ Harald Hanche-Olsen I still have a doubt why $a(x).g(x) + b(x).h(x) = 0$ instead of $a(x).g(x) + b(x).h(x) = gcd(g(x),h(x))$

Comment: $ag+bh$ always has the factor $\gcd(g,h)$. So if $\gcd(g,h)$ has degree at least $1$, then the map in my answer is not onto. And if it is not onto, it is not injective, meaning there is a nontrivial kernel. Take $(a,b)$ in that kernel.